# How to calculate power series with a large norm matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Take this matrix representing the Markov map for seeing a Heads followed by a Tails in a sequence of fair coin flips:
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\  \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2}  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Since the final state is absorbing we can reason that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} M^n = L = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

I am interested in the following limit of a sum for matrices like this.
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \left( n M^n - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}M^i \right)$$
It would seem that I can easily replace $M^n$ with $L$ in the first term but what to do with the actual sum bit??

Ordinarily I'd look at that and think of the power series, except that the norm of $M$ is too big for that to work.

It seems (from empirical evidence) that in this case I get
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}M^i = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 2 & n-6 \\ 2 & 2 & n-4 \\ 0 & 0 & n \end{pmatrix}$$

This means that I can do the limit from above, indeed I get
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \left( n M^n - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}M^i \right) = \begin{pmatrix} -4 & -2 & 6 \\ -2 & -2 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

But how can I do this in general (without a lot of numerical computation each time)? I've tried a few different such Markov maps and I always seem to get convergence even though my matrices always have a norm larger than one. I'd appreciate some help!

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
See greg's post below. Basically if we assume there is a limit (say $S$ for the limit of the partial sums) we can do the following:

$$ n M^n -  \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}M^i = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}  (M^n - M^i) $$
Then 
$$ S = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}  (M^n - M^i) $$
If you take that equation and multiply by $M$ and subtract $I$ you get

$$ S - L = M S - I \Rightarrow (M - I)S = I - L$$

which is the same as what greg had. The problem is that you can't always take the inverse of $(M-I)$; in the cases I considered it is singular.

At this point I noticed that I can always expect the last row of $S$ to be the zero vector as long as $M$ is indeed a right stochastic matrix (as is the case for what I'm doing). In fact the last row of $M$ in an absorbing Markov map is always going to be ${0,\ldots,0,1}$.
So in some sense I'm really mostly interested in the upper rows of the matrix $M$.

Introduce $T$ where $T$ is the identity matrix with the last row zeroed out.

$$ T =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

Then $ S = T S $ and we can replace $M \rightarrow T M$ and $ L \rightarrow T L$
and follow the above logic to get
$$ (T M - I) S =  T - T L = I - L $$
Now we can invert $(T M - I)$ and solve for the limit $S$

$$ S = (T M - I)^{-1} (I - L) $$
I don't know why $(T M - I)$ should always be non-singular but it worked for me for many different choices of $M$ as right-stochastic matrices with the last row ending with one.

I feel like I've answered my own question, although greg's post contains most of this information (before I had a chance to write this all down).

Comment: I think you change basis to Jordan basis. All computations would be really easier.

Comment: The Norm of the Jordan Canonical form for this matrix is even bigger. :(

Oh wait, I have it backwards. Nope it is one exactly, So not sure if that actually helps... :/

Comment: @amcalde with Jordan Canoncial form, it becomes easy to calculate the sum "entry by entry" (with respect to the new basis)

Comment: But $(PDP^{-1})^n = PD^nP^{-1}$ and the powers of the diagonal matrix $D$ are easy to calculate

Comment: Looking at a 4x4 example I get some funky things in the JCF. I get solutions to cubic equations for example. Numerically (without JCF) I can do the same thing and find the limit which is all integers. But using JCF I have to reduce by powers and then sum. It is a total mess. I don't see how that is easier at all. Except that the actual matrix power part just amounts to powers of weird root expressions. Not sure it's a win.

Comment: As for as limits go, however, it's sufficient to note that for any weird root $\lambda$ you get besides $1$, we have $|\lambda| < 1$, so that $\lambda^n \to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and substitute $L$, and your sum becomes
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (L-M^i)
$$
There is some finite index $k$ for which $M^k$ is indistinguishable from $L$.  So terms beyond that index will contribute nothing to the sum.  Once you determine what the cut-off value is, you are left with a finite summation
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k} (L-M^i)
$$

**Update**

Denote the $k^{th}$ partial sum as
$$
 S_k = \sum_{i=0}^{k} (L-M^i)
$$
Using the fact that $ML=LM=L$ we easily find that $LS_k=S_kL=0$.

With a little more effort we can find
$$ \eqalign{
 S_kM = MS_k &= M\sum_{i=0}^{k} (L-M^i) \cr
   &= \sum_{i=0}^{k} (LM-M^{i+1}) \cr
   &= \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (L-M^{i}) \cr
   &= (L-M^{k+1}) - (L-I) + \sum_{i=0}^{k} (L-M^i) \cr
   &= (I-L) + S_k \cr
}$$
where $L=M^{k+1}$ for a large enough $k$.

Finally we can solve for $S_k$
$$ \eqalign{
  (M-I)S_k &= (I-L) \cr
  S_k &= (M-I)^{+}(I-L) \cr
}$$
This should be the solution, but the solution found in the problem statement turns out to be this 
$$ \eqalign{
  S_k &= (I-L)(M-I)^{+}(I-L) \cr
}$$
But I don't see why I'm required to multiply by $(I-L)$.

Comment: I think I have an answer but I'm still working out the details. The answer I came up with does not involve any sum. Well just a matrix inverse and some matrix products.

Comment: I got something very similar but haven't had the chance to get back to writing it up. I'll try to do so now.

Comment: Also $M - I$ is singular. See my update.

Comment: Yes, it's singular. So you must use the pseudoinverse (+) rather than the inverse (-1)

Comment: As long as the limit $L$ exists, whether or not it's an absorbing state, the formula using the pseudoinverse  yields the sum in question.

Comment: If you write this in the form $S = (L-I) (M-I)^{+} (L-I)$ it highlights some interesting special cases. 

First, if $M=L$ then $S=(L-I)$.  

Second, if $M=I$ then $S=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\chi(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial for $M$ and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ be its eigenvalues.
WOLOG, we will assume $|\lambda_1| \ge |\lambda_2| \ge |\lambda_3|$. We have

$$\chi(x) \stackrel{def}{=} \det( xI_3 - M ) = x^3 - \frac32 x^2 + \frac14 x + \frac14 = \prod_{i=1}^3 (x-\lambda_i)
\;\text{ with }\;
\begin{cases}
\lambda_1 &= 1\\
\lambda_2 &= \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}\\
\lambda_3 &= \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}
\end{cases}$$

The key is $1$ is an eigenvalue and the three eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $M$ are all simple.

Apply the [Lagrange interpolating formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) to the constant polynomial $1$ at the 3 points $\lambda_i$, we have

$$1 
= \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{1}{\chi'(\lambda_i)}\prod_{j=1,\ne i}^3( x - \lambda_j)
= \sum_{i=1}^3 \prod_{j=1,\ne i}^3 \frac{x - \lambda_j}{\lambda_i - \lambda_j} 
$$

Lift this polynomial identity to the polynomial ring generated by $M$, 
we obtain a decomposition of the identity matrix $I_3$.

$$I_3 = \sum_{i=1}^3 \Delta_i
\quad\text{ where }\quad
\Delta_i \stackrel{def}{=} \frac{1}{\chi'(\lambda_i)}\prod_{j=1,\ne i}^3 ( M - \lambda_j I ) = \prod_{j=1,\ne i}^3\frac{ M - \lambda_j I }{\lambda_i-\lambda_j}$$

Recall [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) and notice
$$\chi(x) = (x-\lambda_i) \prod_{j=1,\ne i}^3(x - \lambda_j)
\quad\text{ for } i = 1,2,3
$$
We find
$$\chi(M) = 0 
\quad\implies\quad
( M - \lambda_i )\Delta_i = 0 
\quad\iff\quad M \Delta_i = \lambda_i \Delta_i$$
This in turn implies for any polynomial $p(x)$, we have
$$p(M) \Delta_i = p(\lambda_i) \Delta_i, \quad\text{ for } i = 1,2,3$$
One consequence of this is

$$\Delta_i \Delta_j 
= \left(\prod_{k = 1,\ne i}^3\frac{M - \lambda_k I_3}{\lambda_i - \lambda_k} \right)\Delta_j
= \left(\prod_{k = 1,\ne i}^3\frac{\lambda_j - \lambda_k}{\lambda_i - \lambda_k}\right)\Delta_j 
= \begin{cases}\Delta_j, & j = i\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}\tag{*1}
$$
Another consequence is we can reduce any polynomial $p(M)$ in $M$ to a quadratic one:

$$p(M) = p(M) I_3 = p(M)\sum_{i=1}^3 \Delta_i
= \sum_{i=1}^3 p(\lambda_i)\Delta_i\tag{*2}
$$

Apply $(*2)$ to polynomial $p_n(x) = nx^n - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x^k$ and notice $p_n(1) = 0$, we find

$$nM^n - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} M^k = p_n(M) 
= p_n(\lambda_2)\Delta_2 + p_n(\lambda_3)\Delta_3$$

Notice $|\lambda_2|, |\lambda_3| < 1$ and for any $|\lambda| < 1$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n(\lambda) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( n \lambda^n - \frac{\lambda^n -1 }{\lambda - 1} \right) = \frac{1}{\lambda - 1}$$
We find

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n(M) = 
\frac{\Delta_2}{\lambda_2-1} + \frac{\Delta_3}{\lambda_3-1}
= \left[\frac{M-\lambda_3}{(\lambda_2-1)^2(\lambda_2 - \lambda_3)}
 + \frac{M-\lambda_2}{(\lambda_3-1)^2(\lambda_3 - \lambda_2)}\right](M-I_3)
$$
Using the explicit values of $\lambda_2, \lambda_3 = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{4}$,
it is not hard to check
$$\frac{x-\lambda_3}{(\lambda_2-1)^2(\lambda_2 - \lambda_3)}
 + \frac{x-\lambda_2}{(\lambda_3-1)^2(\lambda_3 - \lambda_2)} = 24x + 8$$
This leads to
$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n(M) = (24M + 8I_3)(M - I_3)
&= \begin{bmatrix}20 & 12 & 0\\ 12 & 8 & 12\\ 0 & 0 & 32\end{bmatrix}
\times \frac12 \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & -2 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}-4 & -2 & 6\\ -2 & -2 & 4\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Reproducing what you get numerically.

Alternatively, using $(*2)$, we have
$$M = \sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i \Delta_i
\quad\implies\quad M - I + \Delta_1 = \Delta_1 + (\lambda_2 - 1)\Delta_2 + (\lambda_3 - 1)\Delta_3$$
Combine with $(*1)$, we have

$$(M - I + \Delta_1)\left( \Delta_1 + \frac{\Delta_2}{\lambda_2 - 1} + \frac{\Delta_3}{\lambda_3 - 1}\right) = \Delta_1 + \Delta_2 + \Delta_3 = I_3$$

From this, we get an alternate way to evaluate the limit
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n(M) 
&= \frac{\Delta_2}{\lambda_2 - 1} + \frac{\Delta_3}{\lambda_3 - 1}
= (M - I + \Delta_1)^{-1} - \Delta_1\\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}-\frac12 & \frac12 & 1\\ \frac12 & -1 & \frac32\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^{-1} - 
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}-4 & -2 & 6\\ -2 & -2 & 4\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$